# I have 3 items ['food','drinks','clothes'] as category i want food to be default selected tab when user load page for first time. How can i do it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 3 items ['food','drinks','clothes'] as category.On onclick button i get values but i want food to be default selected tab when user load page for first time. i want food is as useState(foodid).

```
    const Main = () => {
  const [showBlock, setShowBlock] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(getAllCategory());
    store.dispatch(getAllProduct());
  }, []);

  const category = useSelector((state) => state.category.data.categoryList);

  return (
    <div className="app-main">
      <Header />
      <main className={"main-page"}>
        {category.map((cat, index) => (
          <button
            key={cat._id}
            type="button"
            onClick={() => setShowBlock(`${cat._id}`)}
            className={`btn btn--rounded ${
              showBlock === `${cat._id}` ? "btn--active" : ""
            }`}
            style={{ margin: "0.5rem" }}
          >
            {cat.name}
          </button>
        ))}

        <Products show={showBlock === `${showBlock}`} id={showBlock} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply achieve by doing this:

**# create a state for default category**

```js
...
const [defaultCategory, setDefaultCategory] = useState(null);
...
```

**# add `useEffect` to listen category change**

```js
...
const category = useSelector((state) => state.category.data.categoryList);

useEffect(() => {
   setDefaultCategory(category[0])
}, [category]);
...
```

**# pass category to your props/or compare wherever is needed**

```js
...
{defaultCategory
  ? // render first tab (select first tab)
  : null // anything until category load
}
...
```

Comment: bro can you help me how todo it. <Products show={showBlock === `${showBlock}`} id={showBlock} /> is products when user click on food, drinks, clothes button its fetch those categories items.